Sentry CLI Plugin command failed when using npm run build
I'm using Sentry for my existed Nextjs (14.0.4) project
it's okay on dev mode but when I run command npm run build
its fails
I provide terminal error and sentry.client.config.js and next.config.js file
and bellow I provide terminal error when I run npm start
TERMINAL ERROR
// terminal

[@sentry/nextjs] The Sentry Next.js SDK `tunnelRoute` option will not work in combination with Next.js static exports. The `tunnelRoute` option uses serverside features that cannot be accessed in export mode. If you still want to tunnel Sentry events, set up your own tunnel: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/troubleshooting/#using-the-tunnel-option
   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4

(node:11040) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Failed to compile.

Sentry CLI Plugin: Command failed: C:\Users\Sp\Desktop\app\tadvin_front\node_modules\@sentry\cli\sentry-cli.exe releases new tOJsUStMR7bNw0ClAehP6

Sentry CLI Plugin: Command failed: C:\Users\Sp\Desktop\app\tadvin_front\node_modules\@sentry\cli\sentry-cli.exe releases new tOJsUStMR7bNw0ClAehP6


> Build failed because of webpack errors
   Creating an optimized production build  .

sentry.client.config.js file
//sentry.client.config.js

import * as Sentry from "@sentry/nextjs";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "https://ee067c57627c4742a941@sentry.hamravesh.com/6403",

  tracesSampleRate: 1,

  debug: true,

  replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,

  replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,

  integrations: [
    Sentry.replayIntegration({
      maskAllText: true,
      blockAllMedia: true,
    }),
  ],
});

next.config.js file
//next.config.js

const { withSentryConfig } = require("@sentry/nextjs");

const nextConfig = {
  output : 'export',
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  trailingSlash: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "185.243.48.21/",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
};


module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  nextConfig,
  {
    silent: true,
    org: "pettino",
    project: "tadvin_front",
    url: "https://sentry.hamravesh.com/"
  },
  {
    widenClientFileUpload: true,
    transpileClientSDK: true,
    tunnelRoute: "/monitoring",
    hideSourceMaps: true,
    disableLogger: true,
    automaticVercelMonitors: true,
  }
);


https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues
Can you create an issue here with more information? I ran into an issue I believe with this before, and it could be related to turbopack usage in dev mode

-1 because this is not an answer. One of the rules of SO is that an answer must provide a solution to the problem described by the OP. Your answer only provides a link to Github. It should be a comment. Earn more reputation by answering other questions, then you'll be able to add comments to questions.
